# Lazy Loading doesnt display my images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

I have heavy content images. Thats why I decided to use lazy load: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

My page is this one: http://www.mysecretathens.gr/kulte_test/osterman.html

I followed all the instructions that are required but dont understand why the first images that I wanted to test the lazy load function dont display

In my head section is this:

```
   <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the images:

```
 <img class="lazy" src="grey.gif" data-original="osterman/ost21.jpg" width="900" height="602" >
```

and JS code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

 $("img.lazy").lazyload();

</script>
```

Why is only the grey.gif showing up and not the actual image? Any ideas? Do I have the wrong jquery files? Thanks in advance

Comment: what browsers are you using?

Comment: @PhilipBevan Chrome, why?

Comment: chrome debugger shows errors:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery.js:9598

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier lazyload.js:228


Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined osterman.html:205

which suggests your implementation is incorrect. Try looking at downloading the files again. Try using //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js as your jquery src

Comment: and try using http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.8.4/jquery.lazyload.min.js as your lazyload src. Once this is done download these two files, if working and use these.

Comment: can you mark my answer as correct. i will edit in full tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors in chrome debugger:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery.js:9598

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier lazyload.js:228

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined osterman.html:205

Answer (score 1):

Your JS does seem to throw an error. On the bottom of your `jquery.js` file seems to be invalid code:

```
...
})( window );
Window size: x 
Viewport size: x
```

The last two lines cause the error and prevent any further JS execution.